# $ apache2 --version WARNING

Tags: server, apache2

I'm very beginner in this thing

After using `$ apache2 --version` 
It is showing

```
[core:warn] [pid 6371] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 83 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot
```

And when I put my ip address in the URL it shows

`handle($request); $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);`

I'm trying, anyone familiar with that kindly suggest how to overcome this.

Thanks,
Debajyoti

Answer (score 0):

> Syntax error on line 83 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
>   DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot"

```
sudoedit /etc/apache2/apache.conf
```

Go to line 83. The value used for DefaultRuntimeDir seems to be invalid: it does not exist and is not absolute and is not relative to ServerRoot.

So alter the line to a valid directory and save the change. Then restart the apache service and it will be fixed.